# Android Differential app Update

Tags: android, updates

I have a android application hosted separately(not on Play Store), for updating app i have to download complete apk and then install even for small changes and bug fixes.
Is there any way to implement differential update mechanism in my app similar to Google play Store(Smart Update Mechanism)

Answer (score 4):

If your questions is "is there an API that does this all for me?", then the answer is no.

If however you are asking, "What design do I need to implement to do this?", then in outline you need to:

- send info from the client, so that it identifies which version is currently installed
- send the delta between the currently installed version and the new down to the client (in whatever format you deem appropriate - you could just use the output of `bsdiff` for example which is a version of diff that handles binary files)
- read the currently installed apk as a simple binary file, and apply the delta to produce a new binary apk file in a temporary location
- install the new apk from the temporary location
- clean up the temporary location

It's easy to see how this all works smoothly for the Google Play app's case, where the app executing this code is not the app that is being updated. However it can be got to work for updating yourself - after all Google Play also has the need to update itself!

Comment: hi
thanks for the answer!! 
is there is any tutorial or sample app for implementing this!!!

Comment: I don't know of an Android example you could follow.  You may find that the equivalent updater for the Chrome browser as described at http://dev.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette may help you.

Answer (score 2):

The concept that you need to know is "Delta Update":

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_update
```

You must calculate the differences between new and old APK files and generate a Patch file in server-side:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff_utility
https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-gdiff-19970901
https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/software-updates-courgette
```

Then download the patch file in Android client and merge it with the old APK to generate the new one.
Install the new APK...

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, even when you update an app from the Google Play Store, you are downloading a complete APK, even if the update is just to change a single string in your app.

However, I can think of a way (that I have not tried) to update an app differentially. It will be require a server (from which your app will download the new data/update). You will have to write a code in your app that processes the update from the server and replaces the specified resources (values, strings, links, etc) in your app. You won't be able to change the app logic or semantics, but at least the data can be changed.

In conclusion, I think Angry Birds Transformers does something like this (as it keeps telling me it is downloading new data from the servers). But Subway Surfers require you to download a new APK from Play Store in order to get the new resources for every city their tour visits.

Comment: I want to update not just data but app, as changes have made to complete app logic and implementation in app.